# Load annotations for visible region in MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have about 400 MKAnnotationView´s that loads simultaneously into the MKMapView.

I understand that this isn't any good, it is a little bit slow, and I want to do it the "correct" way.

I zoom my map by a center coordinate:

```
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.8;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.8;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.span = span;

region.center = self.selectedCounty.coordinate;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
```

I only want to load the annotations *that could be* visible in that region.

I have a custom MKAnnotation called simply "Annotation" with a CLLocationCoordinate2D- and title-property.

I simply want to load the annotation for the "visible area" on the MKMapView so not all the annotation loads at the same time. And when the "visible area" on the MKMapView changes, I of course want to load annotations for that area.

I know that MKMapView has a delegate method which runs when the region changes.

But how do I know what annotations I should load for that region?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get the map region span and center, and based on the locations of the annotations you could check if any annotation is inside that region... maybe it is implemented already in something like [mapview isAnnotationVisible]... but you'll have to check everyone of the annotations eventually...

Comment: I'm sorry. But i really, really don't understand your answer.

Comment: When I add the annotations to my MapView, I would like to check: if (thisAnnotationBelongsToTheVisibleRegion) then addAnnotation.

Comment: It doesn't exist such a function.

Comment: @FernandoRedondo why did you accept this answer if you do not understand it? The answers bellow give you what you are asking for, maybe you should accept another one instead.

Answer (score 36):

```
MKMapRect visibleMapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;
NSSet *visibleAnnotations = [mapView annotationsInMapRect:visibleMapRect];
```

Comment: this is the right answer, way faster than the method about, it's log n as opposed to N.

Comment: this doesn't work well if map is rotated

Comment: @Nati if the map is rotated and is not in portrait or landscape mode, a visible rectangle is most likely what fits. I guess for this case you can create a new rectangle with some offset...

Answer (score 21):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html

MKMapRectContainsPoint will tell you if it is visible.

```
visibleCount = 0;
for (MyAnnotation *annotation in mapView.annotations) {
    if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)))
    {
        visibleCount++;
    }
}
```

I recommend doing this method on a background thread if you have a lot of annotations. but you can determine if it is visible in the map

Comment: Thanks for the positive votes guys. I am glad this is helping people with their map applications.

Comment: no, this is NOT the correct answer, it requires to check every annotation on the map, see the answer below, and apples documentation for the annotationsInMapRect method that says "This method is much faster than doing a linear search of the objects in the annotations property yourself.", annotationsInMapRect uses a tree to store and search for points.

Comment: @TheLazyCoder in swift 3.0 I am using this method to get annotations
self.annotations(in: self.visibleMapRect).map { obj -> MKAnnotation in return obj as! MKAnnotation }
Which method is faster? the ContainsPoint or this method?